# Laravel - MethodNotAllowedHttpException. Post

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting a **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**. My route is defined and appears in **route:list**. I'm trying to create a record.

This is the route

```
Route::post('add-counsellor/{id}', 'SupportGroupsController@addCounsellor')->name('add-additional-counsellor');
```

its prefixed with /admin/support-groups.

My form is

```
<form action"/admin/support-groups/add-counsellor/{{$data->id}}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="flex-grid__section">
        <label for="counsellor" class="flex-2-col control-label">{{ trans('Add additional Facilitator') }}</label>
        <div class="flex-4-col" id="counsellor_row1">
            <select class="form-control" name="counsellor">
                <option disabled>Select a Facilitator</option>
                @foreach ($counsellor as $key => $couns)
                <option value="{{$key}}">{{$couns}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Add counsellor">
</form>
```

My controller is

```
public function addCounsellor($id){
      $participant = Participant::create(
          [
              'thread_id'     => $id,
              'user_id'       => request($counsellor),
              'last_read'     => new Carbon()
          ]
      );

      return back();
    }
```

Any idea.

Comment: Can you check if there is no duplicate route like `add-counsellor/{anything}`

Comment: 405 method not allowed? if like Mayun says above there is another route with a similar pattern, it might be going there. And it might expect GET or a different HTTP method

Comment: `action="{{action('Addressee_Controller@store')}}"`

Comment: share all routes related to `add-counsellor` ?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error here `<form action"/admin/support-groups/add-counsellor/{{$data->id}}" method="post">` you are missing **=** `<form action="/admin/support-groups/add-counsellor/{{$data->id}}" method="post">`

and yes When you have built in functions by laravel like `url` and `route` then utilize them instead of typing the complete url..

Using `route`:

```
<form action"{{ route('add-additional-counsellor',$data->id) }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="flex-grid__section">
        <label for="counsellor" class="flex-2-col control-label">{{ trans('Add additional Facilitator') }}</label>
        <div class="flex-4-col" id="counsellor_row1">
            <select class="form-control" name="counsellor">
                <option disabled>Select a Facilitator</option>
                @foreach ($counsellor as $key => $couns)
                <option value="{{$key}}">{{$couns}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Add counsellor">
</form>
```

using `url`:

```
<form action="{{ url('admin/support-groups/add-counsellor/'.$data->id) }}" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="flex-grid__section">
            <label for="counsellor" class="flex-2-col control-label">{{ trans('Add additional Facilitator') }}</label>
            <div class="flex-4-col" id="counsellor_row1">
                <select class="form-control" name="counsellor">
                    <option disabled>Select a Facilitator</option>
                    @foreach ($counsellor as $key => $couns)
                    <option value="{{$key}}">{{$couns}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Add counsellor">
    </form>
```

In `route` function you just have to give the name of the route you defined using `->name('route.blah');` and then pass the parameter for the route while in `url` method you can pass the complete route and in the then you can append the parameter using concatenation.
i prefer `route` method because it is easy and simple.

Answer (score 1):

You have error in your form tag there should be `action=` not only `action` and Instead of sending full url in action use `url()` function as below

```
<form action="{{ url('admin/support-groups/add-counsellor/'.$data->id) }}" method="post">
```

Comment: I think this is the reason that he goes to same url with post as `/admin/support-groups/add-counsellor`

Comment: ohh @AndreMacNamara I didn't know that the same answer given after my answer can be accepted on SO ! My efforts are useless

Comment: Neki kar dariya me daal. Parop karaye parmo dharmah.